# How to update a Window from a thread that did not create that Window?

Tags: c++, multithreading, user-interface, winapi

I'd like to create a thread that is capable of updating GUI elements while the main thread (which created the GUI) runs some long calculations, and I don't know how to do this. I'm using the win32 API in MSVC++.

Because these calculations are long and RAM-intensive, I wanted to avoid messing with them and putting these in a thread. This means I'd like to be able to handle this GUI update directly from the thread without the main window having to handle any WndProc messages.

In the simplest case, I just want to be able to update a single static control from inside the thread, but eventually I'd like to be able to draw on the main window or update bitmap images in it as data rolls in from an external device. I don't mean for the thread to ever completely take over the window procedure.

I've tried really simplistic methods, like:

```
// Global
HWND display;
DWORD WINAPI myThread(LPVOID threadParameter);

int APIENTRY WinMain(_In_ HINSTANCE hInstance,
                 _In_opt_ HINSTANCE hPrevInstance,
                 _In_ LPWSTR    lpCmdLine,
                 _In_ int       nCmdShow){

    // Blah Blah Create main Window and display object, which is a "STATIC" Blah Blah

    HANDLE myThreadHandle = CreateThread(0, 0, myThread, (LPVOID)display, 0, &myThreadID);
    HACCEL hAccelTable = LoadAccelerators(hInstance, MAKEINTRESOURCE(IDC_WIN32PROJECT7));

    MSG msg;

    // Main message loop:
    while (GetMessage(&msg, nullptr, 0, 0))
    {
        if (!TranslateAccelerator(msg.hwnd, hAccelTable, &msg))
        {
            TranslateMessage(&msg);
            DispatchMessage(&msg);
        }
    }
    CloseHandle(myThreadHandle);
    return (int) msg.wParam;
}
// other function outside WinMain(){
DWORD WINAPI myThread(LPVOID threadParameter) {
    // I've passed in my static handle here.
    HWND hwnd = (HWND)threadParameter;
    // My hope was that this would update the text of the static window, but...
    PostMessage(hwnd, WM_SETTEXT, 0, (LPARAM)"10");
    // After this message the static window still hasn't updated with the text "10".
    return 0;
};
```

But this doesn't work (the static control just doesn't update) and it's just a guess so I'm probably doing something stupid. I can't find any resources on the proper procedure to do this in C++, but I'm looking for something along the lines of [this MSDN resource](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/csharpfaq/archive/2004/03/17/91685.aspx) (which is in C#).

I can of course upload the whole code of my attempt if this is useful, but I figured that I was probably on the wrong track so I just included this snippet.

Comment: Swap your threads over, background thread long calc, forground/windows thread update the UI.  Post a message from the background thread to the forground windows when the calculation completes,

Comment: What @RichardCritten said.   Window messages only get dispatched when you call GetMessage/DispatchMessage.  If your main thread is busy doing calculations, it won't be available to handle the posted window messages.

Comment: I've thought about that. This might be a separate question then, but the long calc is extremely RAM intensive, as I need to be able to handle several extremely large arrays (up to ~1 GB in extreme cases) and pass them to an external device I'm programming, so I decided I didn't want to mess with putting that in a thread. Are you saying that what I want to do (update the GUI from inside thread) is impossible?

Comment: @aquirdturtle put the arrays on the heap just pass the pointers around.  You cannot update a Window from another thread, it must from the thread that created it.  You have to pump messages on the thread that created the Window for the update/changes to happen.

Comment: Worker threads are called that for a reason, they do work. Don't do work on your UI thread.

Comment: @RichardCritten:  Put your first comment in an answer please?  Then I can upvote it as completely the right answer.

Comment: I'm confused; where in the posted code do the calculations happen?  It looked to me like they would go into myThread() ?

Comment: @HarryJohnston they are not shown. This was a "bare bones" implementation of what I wanted to accomplish.

Comment: @aquirdturtle: yes, I realized that; but where *would* they be if you'd included them?  Without that context, the question is ambiguous.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You cannot have the UI thread do the work, and update the UI from a worker thread. The system simply does not work that way. The main thread needs to remain responsive and process its message queue in a timely fashion. Interaction with windows needs to be performed from the UI thread.

You will simply have to reverse the allocation of work. Have the UI thread work on the UI, and have the worker thread do the intensive work.

You seem concerned that the intensive work will take time and use memory, and that somehow threads are not suited to that task. But that's simply not the case. Threads can use used to perform long running calculations. Threads are able to use memory.

It seems as though you've got yourself in a tizz over nothing. Handle the UI on the UI thread, and do the work on a worker thread. That's all there is to it.

Answer (score 0):

You need to pass a pointer to `HWND display`.

In `CreateThread()` use

```
HANDLE myThreadHandle = CreateThread(0, 0, myThread, (LPVOID)&display, 0, &myThreadID);
```

And in your thread use:

```
HWND hwnd = (HWND)(*threadParameter);
```

> I'd like to create a thread that is capable of updating GUI elements
>   while the main thread (which created the GUI) runs some long
>   calculations

As said in the comments, *work* should be done in the *worker thread*, leaving the main thread handling the drawing, mouse, keyboard, etc. Redrawing a window is only done when the main thread is not busy doing other things, like calculations etc.

Personally, I prefer using user messages for this, and post them to the parent window (instead of posting `WM_SETTEXT` directly to the child window), and let the parent window handle the rest.

Comment: I think I'm trying just that, passing the static handle into my thread and calling postMessage, unless you were suggesting to pass a message to the main window handle instead of the static control handle, and let the WinProc deal with it?

Comment: @aquirdturtle - You need to dereference the parameter (pointer). See update.

Comment: ummm... how can you guarantee HWND has enough bits to hold a pointer?

Comment: @Danny_ds I think you meant  

HWND* hwnd = (HWND*)(threadParameter);
PostMessage(*hwnd, WM_SETTEXT, 0, (LPARAM)"10");

I tried this and it still doesn't update the static control :(

Comment: @aquirdturtle - Also use `(LPVOID)&display` in `CreateThread()`. That should fiw it I guess.

Comment: Doesn't seem to help, the static display isn't updating, no errors or warnings either. Were you assuming that I had some other handling elsewhere in my code? I'm not handling any particular messages outside WM_CREATE, WM_DESTROY, and IDM_EXIT (and defaults). Are you sure that this is even possible, actually? Other comments are indicating otherwise...

Comment: @aquirdturtle - Personally, I prefer using user messages for this, and post them to the parent window (instead of posting WM_SETTEXT directly to the child window), and let the parent window handle the rest.

Comment: @JasonS - I mean a pointer to a HWND. (now HWND itself was passed as being a pointer).